# I can't start my Docker container on Windows 7

Tags: python, docker

My PC runs on Windows 7 x64 and it is a part of a domain. Frankly speaking I haven't been thinking of moving to Windows 10 Pro in a near future although I didn't realize how close I would be to installing it.

I've recently begun reading Django for Professionals 3.0: Production Websites with Python & Django by William S. Vincent and the very first hindrance I came across is Dockers.

Docker Desktop can be installed only on Windows 10 I therefore downloaded Docker Toolbox. For no reason the virtual machine didn't want to boot.... I tried to upgrade Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.2.x version to 6.1.10. Finally it worked although it always wants to be run as an administrator. I don't know if it matters that some files (.docker) located in /Users/Administrator and the others (like .virtualenv of pipenv) in /Users/notebook.....

Anyway.... closer to the point.... I'm unable to start my container.

[Code written in the book](https://github.com/wsvincent/djangoforprofessionals/tree/master/ch2-postgresql)

Here's the process in my terminal:

```
    Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Somet
imes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Machine "default" was started.
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-m
achine env` command.
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regeneratin
g TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...



                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/

docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com


Start interactive shell

Administrator@notebook-pc MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ cd C:/python/django_professionals/chapter1/postgresql

Administrator@notebook-pc MINGW64 /c/python/django_professionals/chapter1/postgr
esql
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  168.4kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.8
 ---> 7f5b6ccd03e9
Step 2/7 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7b68f08f6658
Step 3/7 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6cf532d90680
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c870b6c66708
Step 5/7 : COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
 ---> 55b431e61e7e
Step 6/7 : RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
 ---> Running in c5aa07e5ac12
Collecting pipenv
  Downloading pipenv-2020.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 MB)
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5
  Downloading virtualenv_clone-0.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.0.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
Collecting certifi
  Downloading certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packag
es (from pipenv) (20.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/si
te-packages (from pipenv) (47.1.1)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.0
  Downloading distlib-0.3.0.zip (571 kB)
Collecting six<2,>=1.9.0
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0
  Downloading filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting appdirs<2,>=1.4.3
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: distlib
  Building wheel for distlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for distlib (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for distlib: filename=distlib-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl size=340427
 sha256=ffd8dd029b231bab7f36c48a93deb41ebc003d83bbb76c6782ecb980bb4af9fb
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/eb/4e/d2/a903d4184fb49e4ac06474d6
5715b129aee13d69f7d227e78e
Successfully built distlib
Installing collected packages: virtualenv-clone, distlib, six, filelock, appdirs
, virtualenv, certifi, pipenv
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 certifi-2020.4.5.2 distlib-0.3.0 filelock-3
.0.12 pipenv-2020.6.2 six-1.15.0 virtualenv-20.0.21 virtualenv-clone-0.5.4
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a6086c)
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/b
in/python: not found

Output:
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/b
in/python: not found

Output:
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/b
in/python: not found

Output:
Removing intermediate container c5aa07e5ac12
 ---> cf8a416ce267
Step 7/7 : COPY . /code/
 ---> b427660ce873
Successfully built b427660ce873
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Win
dows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-r
wxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions f
or sensitive files and directories.

Administrator@notebook-pc MINGW64 /c/python/django_professionals/chapter1/postgr
esql
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "postgresql_default" with the default driver
Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.8
 ---> 7f5b6ccd03e9
Step 2/7 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7b68f08f6658
Step 3/7 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6cf532d90680
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c870b6c66708
Step 5/7 : COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
 ---> 5d3f5c973711
Step 6/7 : RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
 ---> Running in d5ef503bac67
Collecting pipenv
  Downloading pipenv-2020.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/si
te-packages (from pipenv) (47.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packag
es (from pipenv) (20.1.1)
Collecting certifi
  Downloading certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.0.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5
  Downloading virtualenv_clone-0.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting appdirs<2,>=1.4.3
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting six<2,>=1.9.0
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0
  Downloading filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.0
  Downloading distlib-0.3.0.zip (571 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: distlib
  Building wheel for distlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for distlib (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for distlib: filename=distlib-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl size=340427
 sha256=807dad54d4f8b388d70ae61e233267f44c846319e9c8c24f7dbf4496f9dc3ec9
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/eb/4e/d2/a903d4184fb49e4ac06474d6
5715b129aee13d69f7d227e78e
Successfully built distlib
Installing collected packages: certifi, appdirs, six, filelock, distlib, virtual
env, virtualenv-clone, pipenv
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 certifi-2020.4.5.2 distlib-0.3.0 filelock-3
.0.12 pipenv-2020.6.2 six-1.15.0 virtualenv-20.0.21 virtualenv-clone-0.5.4
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a6086c):
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/b
in/python: not found

Output:
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/b
in/python: not found

Output:
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/b
in/python: not found

Output:
Removing intermediate container d5ef503bac67
 ---> 7d49adf605d1
Step 7/7 : COPY . /code/
 ---> 125b1ac1973c

Successfully built 125b1ac1973c
Successfully tagged postgresql_web:latest
WARNING: Image for service web was built because it did not already exist. To re
build this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --bui
ld`.
Creating postgresql_web_1 ... done

Administrator@notebook-pc MINGW64 /c/python/django_professionals/chapter1/postgr
esql
$
```

The only way I was able to run the server is omitting **volumes** parameter in **docker-compose.yml** Despite the fact that I get the same error relating to **manage.py** the actual websever runs anyway. 
The second question is that I only reach the webserver by IP address of a virtual adapter (like 192.168.99.100). 127.0.0.1 as described in the book doesn't work.

Should I move to Windows 10 to deal with the problem or.... Should I carry on reading the book implementing code in local machine?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Yep, I've forgotten to mention, when I omit volumes in docker-compose.yml the webserver works.... if I create a superuser like docker-compose exec web python manage.py createsuperuser I expect that it would be also created in local db.sqlite3.... but it isn't. The DBs are different. The created user doesn't exist in a local DB.

Answer (score 0):

Half of the puzzle I solved at night. When it was building an image I found a line:
**Downloading pipenv-2020.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl** It'd installed the latest version of pipenv. I then decided to force it to install an earlier version. I don't know if it was correct to write though it worked. I added **pipenv==2018.11.26** in Dockerfile

```
# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv==2018.11.26 && pipenv install --system
```

I've skipped chapter 2 and did it locally, however here is the process of chapter 3:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.8
3.8: Pulling from library/python
e9afc4f90ab0: Pulling fs layer
989e6b19a265: Downloading [>                                                  ]
e9afc4f90ab0: Downloading [>                                                  ]
 510.4kB/50.39MBwnloading [>                                                  ]
 101.6kB/9.996MBiting
e9afc4f90ab0: Downloading [=>                                                 ]
e9afc4f90ab0: Downloading [=>                                                 ]
  1.53MB/50.39MBiting
989e6b19a265: Downloading [=====>                                             ]
   920kB/7.812MB
af14b6c2f878: Downloading [====>                                              ]
e9afc4f90ab0: Downloading [==>                                                ]
 2.554MB/50.39MB

e9afc4f90ab0: Downloading [===>                                               ]
 3.066MB/50.39MB

989e6b19a265: Downloading [=============>                                     ]
 2.096MB/7.812MB
e9afc4f90ab0: Downloading [====>                                              ]
 4.086MB/50.39MB

e9afc4f90ab0: Downloading [====>                                              ]
 4.606MB/50.39MB
e9afc4f90ab0: Extracting [===========================================>       ]
e9afc4f90ab0: Extracting [=================================================> ]
50.33MB/50.39MBxtracting [=============================================>     ]
989e6b19a265: Extracting [==========================================>        ]
af14b6c2f878: Extracting [=================================================> ]
 9.83MB/9.996MBxtracting [======================>                            ]
5573c4b30949: Extracting [================================================>  ]
50.33MB/51.83MBxtracting [==============================================>    ]
11a88e764313: Extracting [=================================================> ]
11a88e764313: Extracting [=================================================> ]
ee776f0e36af: Extracting [==================================================>]
ee776f0e36af: Pull complete
513c90a1afc3: Pull complete
df9b9e95bdb9: Extracting [==================================================>]
df9b9e95bdb9: Extracting [==================================================>]
df9b9e95bdb9: Pull complete
86c9edb54464: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:dd6cd8191ccbced2a6af5d0ddb51e6057c1444df14e14bcfd5c7b3ef78738050
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.8
 ---> 7f5b6ccd03e9
Step 2/7 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ---> Running in b28d763d8b67
Removing intermediate container b28d763d8b67
 ---> 4966da35178b
Step 3/7 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Running in ab4af6ebaa3f
Removing intermediate container ab4af6ebaa3f
 ---> ca1655c0ba53
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Running in be12616879bd
Removing intermediate container be12616879bd
 ---> 238ca146b9f9
Step 5/7 : COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
 ---> 90c096a097cf
Step 6/7 : RUN pip install pipenv==2018.11.26 && pipenv install --system
 ---> Running in 3b2aa2611d33
Collecting pipenv==2018.11.26
  Downloading pipenv-2018.11.26-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/si
te-packages (from pipenv==2018.11.26) (47.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packa
ges (from pipenv==2018.11.26) (20.1.1)
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
Collecting certifi
  Downloading certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5
  Downloading virtualenv_clone-0.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0
  Downloading filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting six<2,>=1.9.0
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting appdirs<2,>=1.4.3
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.0
  Downloading distlib-0.3.0.zip (571 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: distlib
  Building wheel for distlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for distlib (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for distlib: filename=distlib-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl size=340427
 sha256=ca936027ba8b3e15b02cb9a79b68426ee67750091e72c1ed2eb67a27380096c6
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/eb/4e/d2/a903d4184fb49e4ac06474d6
5715b129aee13d69f7d227e78e
Successfully built distlib
Installing collected packages: filelock, six, appdirs, distlib, virtualenv, cert
ifi, virtualenv-clone, pipenv
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 certifi-2020.4.5.2 distlib-0.3.0 filelock-3
.0.12 pipenv-2018.11.26 six-1.15.0 virtualenv-20.0.23 virtualenv-clone-0.5.4
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (22c09e):
Removing intermediate container 3b2aa2611d33
 ---> 4e1687c3514f
Step 7/7 : COPY . /code/
 ---> abe16389806f

Successfully built abe16389806f
Successfully tagged books_web:latest
Creating books_db_1 ... done
Creating books_web_1 ... done

Administrator@notebook-pc MINGW64 /c/python/django_professionals/code/books
$ docker-compose logs
Attaching to books_web_1, books_db_1
web_1  | python: can't open file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or di
rectory
db_1   | ***********************************************************************
*********
db_1   | WARNING: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD has been set to "trust". This will a
llow
db_1   |          anyone with access to the Postgres port to access your databas
e without
db_1   |          a password, even if POSTGRES_PASSWORD is set. See PostgreSQL
db_1   |          documentation about "trust":
db_1   |          https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
db_1   |          In Docker's default configuration, this is effectively any oth
er
db_1   |          container on the same system.
db_1   |
db_1   |          It is not recommended to use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust.
Replace
db_1   |          it with "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" instead to set a passw
ord in
db_1   |          "docker run".
db_1   | ***********************************************************************
*********
db_1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "post
gres".
db_1   | This user must also own the server process.
db_1   |
db_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1   |
db_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1   |
db_1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... o
k
db_1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1   | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
db_1   | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1   |
db_1   | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1   |
db_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1   |
db_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1   |
db_1   | waiting for server to start....2020-06-13 00:12:08.901 UTC [46] LOG:  s
tarting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compil
ed by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.902 UTC [46] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/r
un/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.919 UTC [47] LOG:  database system was shut down at
 2020-06-13 00:12:08 UTC
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.924 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is ready to acce
pt connections
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   |
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb
.d/*
db_1   |
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.989 UTC [46] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1   | waiting for server to shut down....2020-06-13 00:12:08.992 UTC [46] LOG
:  aborting any active transactions
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.996 UTC [46] LOG:  background worker "logical repli
cation launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.997 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.009 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server stopped
db_1   |
db_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1   |
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.130 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian
12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
, 64-bit
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.131 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.
0", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.131 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", p
ort 5432
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.137 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/ru
n/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.152 UTC [55] LOG:  database system was shut down at
 2020-06-13 00:12:09 UTC
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.155 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accep
t connections

Administrator@notebook-pc MINGW64 /c/python/django_professionals/code/books
$ docker-compose up
books_db_1 is up-to-date
Starting books_web_1 ... done
Attaching to books_db_1, books_web_1
db_1   | ***********************************************************************
*********
db_1   | WARNING: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD has been set to "trust". This will a
llow
db_1   |          anyone with access to the Postgres port to access your databas
e without
db_1   |          a password, even if POSTGRES_PASSWORD is set. See PostgreSQL
db_1   |          documentation about "trust":
db_1   |          https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
db_1   |          In Docker's default configuration, this is effectively any oth
er
db_1   |          container on the same system.
db_1   |
db_1   |          It is not recommended to use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust.
Replace
db_1   |          it with "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" instead to set a passw
ord in
db_1   |          "docker run".
db_1   | ***********************************************************************
*********
db_1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "post
gres".
db_1   | This user must also own the server process.
db_1   |
db_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1   |
db_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1   |
db_1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... o
k
db_1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1   | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
db_1   | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1   |
db_1   | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1   |
db_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1   |
db_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1   |
db_1   | waiting for server to start....2020-06-13 00:12:08.901 UTC [46] LOG:  s
tarting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compil
ed by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.902 UTC [46] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/r
un/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.919 UTC [47] LOG:  database system was shut down at
 2020-06-13 00:12:08 UTC
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.924 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is ready to acce
pt connections
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   |
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb
.d/*
db_1   |
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.989 UTC [46] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1   | waiting for server to shut down....2020-06-13 00:12:08.992 UTC [46] LOG
:  aborting any active transactions
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.996 UTC [46] LOG:  background worker "logical repli
cation launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:08.997 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.009 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server stopped
db_1   |
db_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1   |
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.130 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian
12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
, 64-bit
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.131 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.
0", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.131 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", p
ort 5432
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.137 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/ru
n/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.152 UTC [55] LOG:  database system was shut down at
 2020-06-13 00:12:09 UTC
db_1   | 2020-06-13 00:12:09.155 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accep
t connections
web_1  | python: can't open file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or di
rectory
books_web_1 exited with code 2
```

There is another one problem persists:

**web_1  | python: can't open file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

It creates two images.... 
**Creating books_db_1 ... done
Creating books_web_1 ... done**

They are displayed in Kitematic (Alpha) although **books_web_1** is stopped. When I try to start it I get an error
**python: can't open file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

As for localhost, should I use somewhere **network_mode: host** parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, eventually... I've watched a video by Bret Fisher who said that it would be impossible to run a project from a directory none other than \User\USERNAME

Once I copied it there (mind.... that there could be many of them, you should copy it into a user's directory you're currently logged in **PROVIDED** you're an administrator **if not** copy the project to the administrator directory. My computer is a part of a domain therefore the latter is the case of mine.

The only thing I didn't work out yet.... is how to run a web server on localhost... It only opens a web page at http://192.168.99.100:8000